# Java lwjgl and slick are not displaying my textures

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl, slick2d

I have tried a lot of different things, but nothing worked so far. at first, the problem was that there was just a blank screen when the program was run. I finally got it to display a blank white square. My images are 128x128 and the other is 512x512.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;
import org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import java.util.Random;

public class TextureDemo
{
private static Texture wood;
Random random = new Random();

    public TextureDemo()
{
    initGL(640, 480, "SLICK TEXTURES");
loadTexture("mozilla");

int x = 100, y = 100, count = 0, width = 0, height = 0, counter = 10;

    while(true)
    {
        count++;
        if(count == counter)
        {
            x--; y--; width++; height++; counter += random.nextInt(50) + 1;
        }

                render(x, y, width, height);
        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);

        if(Display.isCloseRequested())
        {
            wood.release();
            Display.destroy();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}


private void initGL(int width, int height, String title)
{
    try
        {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width, height));
    Display.setTitle(title);
    Display.create();
    }
    catch(LWJGLException e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Display.destroy();
    System.exit(1);
    }

    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, 1, -1);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

}


public void loadTexture(String key)
{
    try
    {
        wood = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("./res/images/"+key+".png"));
    System.out.println("working." + wood.getTextureID());
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Display.destroy();
    System.exit(1);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}


public void render(int x, int y, int width, int height)
{

    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    System.out.println("working." + wood.getTextureID());

            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);

                GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, wood.getTextureID());
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x, y);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x + wood.getImageWidth(), y);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x + wood.getImageWidth(), y + wood.getImageHeight());
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x, y + wood.getImageHeight());

    GL11.glEnd();
    System.out.println(wood.getHeight()+ " " +wood.getWidth());


}

    public static void main (String[] args)
{
    new TextureDemo();
}


}
```

I just want to be able to see the png's i have in the program. Soany ideas why i'm getting white images? how important is the order of the initGL method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about it, but I think you had to `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` in this old deprecated OpenGL style. (Instead of GL_TEXTURE)

**Update**: I really think you should do `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);`. Try using a gray clear color. Maybe they just turned into black squares instead of whites.
Slick has a function to bind the texture (I'm not sure what getTextureID returns).

**Update:** Make sure you first `glBindTexture` and then `glBegin`.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the problem gets worse when i do that. the screen goes back to not doing anything. The only exception is if I only change GL11.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D); it stays the same if its changed to that. But if i do glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) then it goes back to not doing anything at all D:

Comment: how would I make a gray color?

Comment: call once `glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);` in your init section.

Comment: getTextureID just returns the number texture loaded it is. since there is only 1 texture, the ID is 1. if there were more textures loaded i believe it would just go up 1 for each new texture. and if it returns 0, then the texture was never loaded properly. And why would this make a black square where my texture is??? That would suck, because i didn'v even want for that to happen. and gratzi for that

Comment: the clearcolor exposed that there is indeed a black square floating where the texture should be. So does this mean that the black square is being drawn after my texture? Or is the texture for some reason coming out as black?

Comment: The texture is coming out in black. So the shader is not sampling the texture. Try calling `glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);`. That is only a guess.

Comment: its still returning the same. I also fixed the texcoords that were wrong. Im not sure if the texture maybe needs to be unbinded?

Comment: Bind your texture before calling glBegin. That does not work otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I think your texturecoords are wrong. Try replacing with this:

```
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    GL11.glVertex2f(x, y);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    GL11.glVertex2f(x + wood.getImageWidth(), y);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    GL11.glVertex2f(x + wood.getImageWidth(), y + wood.getImageHeight());
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    GL11.glVertex2f(x, y + wood.getImageHeight());
```